# property of ellipse

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

In my book there is an statement for a ellipse.

Referring to the below ellipse:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

The statement is

The product of the length of the perpendicular segments from the focii on any tangent to the ellipse is $b^2$ and the feet of perpendicular lie on its auxiliary circle and the tangents at these feet to the auxiliary circle meet on the ordinate of P and that the locus of their point of intersection is similar to ellipse as that of the original one.

I could not understand the statement. Can anybody explain it to me with a DIAGRAM(FIGURE) in simple words.

Comment: For the auxiliary circle part, there is [this diagram](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020209/rolling-ellipse-on-line-tangent-and-normal-of-roulette)

Comment: But I could not understand @Gribouillis

Comment: That's still vague. Which parts of the statement are hard to understand? The auxiliary circle? The foot of a perpendicular?

Comment: @J.M.     In the second line after the word 'and'

Comment: Could anyone provide me a figure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Hints:**
>
> - $\Delta ACD \sim \Delta BCE$
> - Let $(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)=
>   \left( \dfrac{AD}{AC},\dfrac{CD}{AC} \right)=
>   \left( \dfrac{BE}{BC},\dfrac{CE}{BC} \right)$ so that $AD\times BE=AC\times BC \cos^2 \theta$
> - $AC+BC=2a$
> - $AB=2\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$
> - $(DC+CE)^2+(AD-BE)^2=AB^2$
> - $F$ lies on the ellipse $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{b^2y^2}{a^4}=1$

[image]

**Addendum:**

For hyperbola $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, there are similar properties except the locus gives the **re-scaled** conjugate hyperbola

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{b^2y^2}{a^4}=1$$

with their transverse axes in common instead of asymptotes.

[image]

Comment: Red and blue ellipses are inversions with respect to green auxiliary circle.. Right?

Comment: @Narasimham  Wow! Good observation that I missed it.

Comment: The inversion is not radial but along $y; CF $ is parallel to $y-$ axis

Comment: Yes, what a wonderful property!

Comment: Could you please draw a similar diagram for hyperbola?

Comment: http://imgur.com/GXwuuUu properties are pretty similar

Comment: @Mrigank Updated with the hyperbola case.

Comment: Thanks, I tried too, has some more properties.. http://m.imgur.com/kGnrTgC

Comment: Yes, as pointed out from comment of @Narasimham