# Orthogonal and isogonal trajectories of tangent for hyperbola and ellipse.

Tags: tangent-line

I'm trying to understand a task from [DIFFERENTIAL and INTEGRAL CALCULUS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0714700703)
102. Find curves for which the product of the distance of any tangent line
to two given points is constant.
Answer: Ellipses and hyperbolas. (Orthogonal and isogonal trajectories.)
What did Piskunov mean under two given points? Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it what means by $AD \times BE=b^2$ in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059564/property-of-ellipse/2060603#2060603)?

Comment: Ellipse and hyperbola are known to be the curves for which product of perpendicuklars from foci to any tangent is constant. However , this question of Piskonov  is in more general setting. For instance the given points may be $(\pm k,0)$ where $k$ not necesarily $2ae$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Further thoughts based on my comment above**

Let the two given points be $(\pm c,0)$, and the tangent be $y=mx+k$,

Now

$$\frac{mc+k}{\sqrt{1+m^2}} \times \frac{-mc+k}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}= \pm b^2$$

Positive (constant product) when the points are on the same side of the tangent whereas negative are opposite.

$$\frac{k^2-m^2c^2}{1+m^2}=\pm b^2$$

$$k^2=m^2(c^2 \pm b^2) \pm b^2$$

Take $a^2=c^2 \pm b^2$,

$$(y-mx)^2=a^2m^2 \pm b^2$$

which is known as the magical equation to the tangent of an ellipse $(+)$ or a hyperbola $(-)$ with slope $m$.  The curve is an envelope of a family of tangents, namely

$$F(x,y)\equiv (mx-y)^2-(a^2 m^2 \pm b^2)=0$$

Solving $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial m}=F=0$$

will give the curves.

Answer (score 1):

After @Ng Chung Tak

$mx-y=\pm \sqrt{a^2m^2\pm b^2}$. Next, let us take only upper signs, then
$y=mx-\sqrt{a^2m^2+b^2}, m=dy/dx$, this is a Clairaut equation
$$y=xy'-\sqrt{a^2 y'^2+b^2}~~~~(1)$$
representing the family of tangents to a fixed curve ; the fixed curve is obtained by differentiating (1) w.r.t. $x$, we get
$$x-\frac{a^2y'}{\sqrt{a^2y'^2+b^2}}=0~~~(2)$$ apart from the general equation $y''=0$. Solving (2), we get
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{bx}{a\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} \implies y=\frac{b}{a}\int \frac{x dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} \implies y=\frac{b}{a} \sqrt{a^2-x^2}.$$
$$\implies \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1,$$
which is an ellipse. Similarly, by considering lower signs above for $\pm$, we can get a hyperbola.

For Clairaut equation see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation