# Show that the product of the lengths of the perpendiculars drawn from two points to a straight line is $b^2$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

**Question:**

Show that the product of the lengths of the perpendiculars drawn from the points $(\pm c,0)$ to the straight line $bx\cos\theta+ay\sin\theta-ab=0$ is $b^2$ when $a^2=b^2+c^2$.

---

**My attempt:**

Let, the length of the perpendicular on drawn upon $bx\cos\theta+ay\sin\theta-ab=0$ from $(c,0)$ is $d_1$ and the length of that drawn upon the same from $(-c,0)$ is $d_2$. Now,

$$d_1=\frac{|bc\cos\theta+0-ab|}{\sqrt{b^2\cos^2\theta+a^2\sin^2\theta}}$$

$$\implies d_1=\frac{|bc\cos\theta-ab|}{\sqrt{b^2\cos^2\theta+a^2\sin^2\theta}}$$

Again,

$$d_2=\frac{|-bc\cos\theta-ab|}{\sqrt{b^2\cos^2\theta+a^2\sin^2\theta}}$$

Now,

$$d_1d_2=\frac{|-(bc\cos\theta-ab)(bc\cos\theta+ab)|}{{b^2\cos^2\theta+a^2\sin^2\theta}}$$

$$\implies d_1d_2=\frac{|a^2b^2-b^2c^2\cos^2\theta|}{{b^2\cos^2\theta+a^2\sin^2\theta}}$$

$$\implies d_1d_2=\frac{|a^2b^2-b^2c^2\cos^2\theta|}{{b^2\cos^2\theta+a^2(1-\cos^2\theta)}}$$

$$\implies d_1d_2=\frac{|a^2b^2-b^2c^2\cos^2\theta|}{{b^2\cos^2\theta+a^2-a^2\cos^2\theta}}$$

$$\implies d_1d_2=\frac{|a^2b^2-b^2c^2\cos^2\theta|}{a^2-(a^2-b^2)\cos^2\theta}$$

$$\implies d_1d_2=|\frac{b^2(a^2-c^2\cos^2\theta)}{a^2-(a^2-b^2)\cos^2\theta}|$$
[$a^2-(a^2-b^2)\cos^2\theta$ is positive, so bringing it inside the modulus sign doesn't make a difference]

$$\implies d_1d_2=|\frac{b^2(a^2-(a^2-b^2)\cos^2\theta)}{(a^2-(a^2-b^2)\cos^2\theta)}|$$
[Given, $a^2=b^2+c^2\implies c^2=a^2-b^2$]

$$d_1d_2=|b^2|$$(shown?)

The question asked me to show that $d_1d_2=b^2$, but I showed them that $d_1d_2=|b^2|$. So, is there something wrong with my process, or is there something wrong with the question?

Comment: $\forall b\in \mathbb{R}$, $b^2=(-b)^2=|b|^2=|b^2|. \,$  See [my post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852013/orthogonal-and-isogonal-trajectories-of-tangent-for-hyperbola-and-ellipse/3852040#3852040) for your interest.  For visualization, please also refer another post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059564/property-of-ellipse/2060603#2060603).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Note that the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) of a real number $x$ is defined by

$$|x|=\begin{cases}x,\space\text{if}x\geq0 \\ -x,\space\text{if} x<0\end{cases}$$

and since $b^2\geq 0$ for all $b\in\mathbb R$ we have $|b^2|=b^2$.

Answer (score 3):

*Comment*

Btw, the product of the length of the perpendiculars drawn from the focal points of an ellipse $(\pm c,0)$ to the tangent straight line $bx\cos\theta+ay\sin\theta-ab=0$ is $b^2$ when $a^2=b^2+c^2$.

[image]

Can be also derived from  Newton's ellipse canonical form.

Comment: [+1] Nice remark ! It could be said as a preambule that the set of lines of the given form is exactly the set of tangents to the  ellipse with canonical equation $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$, and therefore that $c$ can be interpreted as the half focal distance.

Comment: Same figure [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2060603)

Comment: Thanks to you. !  I had almost forgotten about them.